# Why am I getting an error connected with Unexpected token instead of 'else' and 'else if'

Tags: javascript

I'm writting a code that should make a keyless car.So when you type your age it should say the following:

1) IF they say they are below 18, respond with:
  "Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off"

2) IF they say they are 18, respond with:
  "Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!"

3) IF they say they are over 18, respond with:
   "Powering On. Enjoy the ride!"

I should use JS conditions such as:
if,
else,
else if

When I'm saying 'else'(3rd condition) then the block of code should be executed if the condition1 is false and condition2 is false. So they are both false.
I've tried to use 'else if' instead of 'else' and it worked, but then i dont understand a difference between them.

```
var age = prompt("Good day! What is your age?:");
if (age < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (age === 18) {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
} else (age > 18) {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

I was expecting an alert message with a correct text, but it giving me an error with last 'else':
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

Comment: `else` should not have a condition that is causing the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the condition in your **else**

```
var age = prompt("Good day! What is your age?:");

// Betwen 0 and 17 years old
if (age < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
}
// Exactly 18 years old
else if (age === 18) {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
}
// We don't care about her age here :-D
else {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Else should not have condition, because code in else is executed when no conditions are matched.

**Edit:** as Maheer Ali mentioned, you should also convert the `var age` to int.

```js
var age = prompt("Good day! What is your age?:");
    age = parseInt(age);

if (age < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (age === 18) {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
} else {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```

Comment: Also mention that he `age` will be a string. He needs to convert it to integer using Unary Plus `var age = +prompt("Good day! What is your age?:");`

Answer (score 0):

`else` should not have a condition: (remove the `(age > 18)` part )

also make sure to cast your string value to int to make comparisons (<>=)

```
var age = prompt("Good day! What is your age?:");
if (age < 18) {
    alert("Sorry, you are too young to drive this car. Powering off");
} else if (age === 18) {
    alert("Congratulations on your first year of driving. Enjoy the ride!");
} else {
    alert("Powering On. Enjoy the ride!");
}
```